# Shell script: run screen, open several screens and run a command in each

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell, ubuntu-18.04

Pretty much what the title says:

My shell script should

- Run command A, wait until done
- run "screen"
- run command B1 in initial screen
- open new window (usually via Cmd-a-c)
- run command B2 in new window
- open new window
- run command B3 in new window

That's it, no need to wait until some (or all) are done, although that would give bonus points. How could I do this?

Comment: Do yourself a favor, switch to `tmux` from `screen`, it is much better terminal multiplexer. Answer to your question : https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/152740

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start a background `screen` name the session "mysession":

```
screen -d -m -S mysession
```

Run `top` in the first window

```
screen -S mysession -X exec top
```

Start another window, name it "win1" and run "`vmstat 10`" in it

```
screen -S mysession -X screen -t win1
screen -S mysession -p win1 -X exec vmstat 10
```

Start another window, name it "win2" and run "`iostat 30`" in it

```
screen -S mysession -X screen -t win2 
screen -S mysession -p win2 -X exec iostat 30
```

To connect and see the session:

```
screen -x -S mysession
```

If any of the programs exit, the window won't close as `screen` will have started a shell in each (that you can use if required).

*- OR -* if you only want a single command per window, or want to more easily clean up after the processes are complete, don't run the default shell in each window, just the command(s):

```
screen -d -m -S mysession top
screen -S mysession -p 0 -X title win0    # optional!
screen -S mysession -X screen -t win1 vmstat 10
screen -S mysession -X screen -t win2 iostat 30
```

`screen` will "terminate" the window (possibly leaving the window contents intact, see `zombie` below) when the process exits, or to shut them down:

```
screen -S mysession -X quit   # nuke whole the session
```

or

```
screen -S mysession -p win2 -X kill
screen -S mysession -p win1 -X kill
screen -S mysession -p 0 -X kill
```

(this may or may not kill any running processes, `screen` will send each a SIGHUP though)

If you want `screen` to auto-close windows, and exit when all processes are done, add this after you create the session (though if you don't have `zombie` set in your `.screenrc`, this is probably the default anyway):

```
screen -S mysession -X zombie
```

That unsets the "zombie" close and resurrect keys, windows then disappear when the command in each window terminates, `screen` itself will close when the last window does. (You might need to use `defzombie` instead of `zombie`, but only the latter works for me, despite documentation to the contrary.)

Comment: Great answer. For the sake of completeness, if I wanted to run more than one command in one single screen window, I can put it where ever and it will get queued once the previous window-specific command has finished?

Comment: If you do this with multiple `screen -X exec` invocations the programs will run concurrently sharing the same window, which isn't usually what you want ;-) Try something like `screen -S mysession -X screen -t win1 -X sh -c "command1; command2"` to run them sequentially.